# Switching between pages for Flat Navigation Design

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows store app using C#/XAML and the design I Would like to implement is the "Flat Design" described at [MSDN Navigation Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761500.aspx).

For example, The Top Navigation bar will have "Files", "Photos" and "Music". Selecting an icon should display the appropriate page (say Files). The user can click on a folder in that view and that can navigate into the folder. The user then can click to Photos to display Photos list etc

The examples I see are all showing method to navigate between pages using the "Frame.Navigate(typeof(targetpage))" method and this for the hierarchical model.

What would be the method to switch between multiple (pre constructed) pages which can have hierarchical navigation while maintaining the state of the pages.?

For example, like the tabbar in IOS (we have multiple view controllers to switch between and is attached to the tabbar).

Thanks

Comment: Figured it out. Oddly hard to search and find. This can be accomplished by 1. Creating a bunch of "Frame" objects. Each Frame provides a navigation context to navigate through a series of pages. 2. Switch between frames based on the top navigation bar and manage states.